# Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.measurement.DynamiteMeasurementManager"

Tags: android, admob

My app uses `play-services-ads:18.2.0`.
On devices with Android API below 28 there is this error log:

```
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:300
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 300
W/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version < 2, falling back to loadModule2
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:7 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:0
I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite
W/Ads: #007 Could not call remote method. @28
    com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaxj: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: Failed to instantiate module class: com.google.android.gms.ads.measurement.DynamiteMeasurementManager
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaxh.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.2.0:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzajp.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.2.0:17)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzajp.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.2.0:44)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzajo.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.2.0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: Failed to instantiate module class: com.google.android.gms.ads.measurement.DynamiteMeasurementManager
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.instantiate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaxh.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.2.0:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzajp.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.2.0:17) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzajp.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.2.0:44) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzajo.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.2.0) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.measurement.DynamiteMeasurementManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000031/AdsDynamite.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at ad.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@12874009@12.8.74 (020308-204998136):6)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.instantiate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaxh.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.2.0:1) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzajp.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.2.0:17) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzajp.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.2.0:44) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzajo.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.2.0) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.measurement.DynamiteMeasurementManager
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at ae.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@12874009@12.8.74 (020308-204998136):130)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 8 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

This error log is written before even `Application.onCreate()` is called.
(Probably while the Manifest is parsed).

Is it possible to fix those errors e.g. by adding some dependencies?

Comment: I'm also seeing this `com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:21.2.0`